# Summing up data with the same conditions in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

df =

| col1 | Num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

I want to add all the numbers and show the total.

So I will get:

| col1 | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('col1').sum()
```

If you wanted the new column to have the name 'sum' as in your example you could do the following:

```
df1 = df.groupby('col1').sum()
df1.columns = ['Sum']
```